# How can I show the error message for the _confirm field in freeform when matching_fields does not validate?

Tags: solspace-freeform, validation

I'm trying to display an inline validation error when these two fields do not match:

```
 {freeform:field:email} 
 {freeform:field:email_confirm}
```

Which outputs the following html:

```
 <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="freeform_email">
 <input type="text" name="email_confirm" value="" id="freeform_email_confirm">
```

And I have the `matching_fields="email"` parameter set in the freeform tag.

And I have this configured for the error messages:

```
 {if freeform:error:email}Please fill in your email<br>{/if}
 {if freeform:error:email_confirm}Confirm email does not match<br>{/if}
```

The issue is that if the fields do not match, it displays the message from the `email` field rather than the `email_confirm` field.

So if the error is because the confirm email doesn't match or isn't populated, the *"Please fill in your email"* message obviously doesn't make sense.

Is it possible to display the `email_confirm` error in this case?